# Insert distinct values SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert, distinct-values

I'm trying to insert unique values into a table from a View. I have a table as below:
the "fromView" has no unique constraint in passport

```
id  | passport | name | surname | address 
1      44543     John    Smith     xxxxx
2      10001     Mike    Thomps    avasfa
3      10001     Mike    Thomps    avasfa
4      10001     Mike    Thomps    avasfa
5      14221     Robert  Martinez  lkjij3
```

my "toTable" has the same data structure but with a unique constraint in passport column.

my insert query is this:

```
INSERT into toTable (id, passport, name, surname, address) 
SELECT (id, passport, name, surname, address) 
FROM fromView a 
WHERE passport IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                           FROM toTable b
                                           WHERE b.passport = a.passport)
```

but this give me the error below:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'toTable' with unique index 'toTable_Passport_Unique'.

So, I Don't know how to insert unique values into my table. Thanks in advance

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of all passports with multiple entries by running this query:

```
Select Passport, Count (*) NumEntries
From  fromTable
Group by Passport
Having Count (*) > 1
```

Then you have to decide what to do with these duplicate rows. Run the following query to see the full row for these duplicates:

```
Select *
From  fromTable
Where Passport In
(
    Select Passport, Count (*) NumEntries
    From  fromTable
    Group by Passport
    Having Count (*) > 1
)
Order by Passport
```

Let's say you decide to go with the newest row inserted for each passport (meaning the Id would be the highest), this query will give you the data you need.

```
Select T1.*
From  fromTable T1
Where Id In
(
    Select Max (Id) Id
    From  fromTable
    Group by Passport
)
```

You can insert using

```
INSERT into toTable (id, passport, name, surname, address) 
Select T1.*
From  fromTable T1
Where Id In
(
    Select Max (Id) Id
    From  fromTable
    Group by Passport
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into toTable (id, passport, name, surname, address)
select id, passport, name, surname, address
from (
      select *,
             row_number() over(partition by passport order by id) as rn
      from fromTable
     ) as T
where rn = 1
```

Comment: i really doesnt know about row_numer() and partition, but this is working, thanks!

Comment: @grteibo - Read more about it here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that for the same `passport`, we will have the same `name`, `surname`, and `address`, and we only want the most recent (highest) `id` then try,

```
INSERT INTO toTable (id, passport, name, surname, address)
SELECT max(id), passport, name, surname, address
FROM fromTable
--optional WHERE clause in case there's already data in toTable:
WHERE passport NOT IN (SELECT to.passport from toTable [to])
GROUP BY passport, name, surname, address
```

Comment: @Widow - that's a bad assumption

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *that* bad - we are dealing with passports, after all, and the example table includes the same assumption.

Comment: People change addresses all the time, and sometimes names. I would not want to make that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into toTable (id, name, surname, addr, passport)
  select
    testA1.id, testA1.name, testA1.surname, testA1.addr, testA1.passport 
  from 
    fromTable as testA1 right join (select min(id) AS distinctID, passport from fromTable group by passport) as testA2 on 
    testA2.distinctID = testA1.id
```